# Using a circle SVG, how to animate a dashed progress bar to show a certain percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I currently have an SVG with three circle elements.

- Circle 1: Grey border (bottom layer)
- Circle 2: Red Dashed border (mid layer)
- Circle 3: Blue border (top layer)

I am able to animate the Circle 3 (Blue) to show 40%.

Unfortunately though, Circle 2 (Red) is around the entire circle (100%) instead of 80%.

So my questions are...

1. Can Circle 2 be animated the same as Circle 3 and occupy only 80%? Or is it not possible because of stroke-dasharray: 0.2em (line 93 in the CSS)?
2. In the css (line 81 and line 87), I have vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke commented out. I would like to uncomment those two lines but unfortunately the progress circular bar doesn't look correct. Any possible way to make the stroke not responsive while having the desired animation/look?

Any help is appreciated!

Here's the Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaVrpE

P.S.
I'm able to do the animation by adding the "active" class to the circle elements. That class gets added by the buttons. Finally, the "active" class calls the keyframe names in the CSS.

Snippet of the HTML and CSS codes but please do check out the codepen above.

HTML

```
<svg id="categoryIcon" data-name="category icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 96 96" width="100%" height="100%" class="catIcon userIcon">
    <circle class="filler-loader fill-line" cx="48" cy="48" r="47" />
    <circle class="filler-loader path path-dashed" cx="48" cy="48" r="47" />
    <circle class="filler-loader path path-progress" cx="48" cy="48" r="47" />
    <path d="M1536 1399q0 109-62.5 187t-150.5 78H469q-88 0-150.5-78T256 1399q0-85 8.5-160.5t31.5-152 58.5-131 94-89T583 832q131 128 313 128t313-128q76 0 134.5 34.5t94 89 58.5 131 31.5 152 8.5 160.5zm-256-887q0 159-112.5 271.5T896 896 624.5 783.5 512 512t112.5-271.5T896 128t271.5 112.5T1280 512z" transform="translate(26, 25), scale(0.025)"/>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg.catIcon {
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  .filler-loader {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  }

  .fill-line {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #e3e3e3;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    // vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
  }

  .path {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 8px;
    // vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
    stroke-dasharray: $dashOffset;
    stroke-dashoffset: $dashOffset;

    &-dashed {
      &.active {
        stroke-dasharray: 0.2em;
        stroke: red;
      }
    }

    &-progress {
      &.active {
        stroke: blue;
      }
    }

  }

  &.userIcon {
    .path-dashed {
      &.active {
        animation: circProgress80 1.5s cubic-bezier(.6, .09, 0, .94) forwards;
        clip-path: url("#circleMask");
      }
    }

    .path-progress {
      &.active {
        animation: circProgress40 1.5s cubic-bezier(.6, .09, 0, .94) forwards;
      }
    }
  }

}
```